# Shell script to loop and delete

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, sh

Could someone help me on this.I have below folder structure as shown below .I want to loop through every folder inside the backuptest and delete all the folders except today date folder.i want it run as a cron job

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Comment: In your question you ask to write the code from scratch. Better approach is to try to do it by yourself and ask more [specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get today's date in whatever format you require via the `date` command.  For example,

```
TODAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

You can loop over the subfolders you want with a simple wildcard match:

```
for d in /path/to/backuptest/*/*; do
  # ...
done
```

You can strip the directory portion from a file name with the `basename` command:

```
name=$(basename path/to/file)
```

You can glue that together something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

for d in /path/to/backuptest/*/*; do
  test "$(basename "$d")" = "$TODAY" || rm -rf "$d"
done
```

### Update:

If you don't actually want to purge *all* subfolders except today's, but rather only those matching some particular name pattern, then one way to accomplish that would be to insert that pattern into the glob in the `for` command.  For example, here

```
for d in /path/to/backuptest/*/+([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9]); do
  test "$(basename "$d")" = "$TODAY" || rm -rf "$d"
done
```

the only files / directories considered for deletion are those whose names consist of three nonempty, hyphen-separated strings of decimal digits.  One could write patterns that more precisely match date string format if one preferred, but it does get messier the more discriminating you want the pattern to be.

Comment: can you edit the script to just delete the date folders ?because i may have other folders in the directory which has different name and i don't want to delete them.for example in backup folder i may have folder like testscripts or insider the server1 folder i may have test folder.i dont want to remove these folders i just want to delete the folders which has name

Comment: @user6238251, It is possible to limit the scope of folders eligible for deletion, but exactly what test do you propose to use to distinguish "date folders" from other folders?

Comment: the "date folders" are backups with the backupdate and other folders are just with anyother normal name....

Comment: @user6238251 This is not a free coding site. You already got few different solutions even if you didn't paste a piece of code. Just look at the answers and you can do it yourself. If not then show us what you did and then we can help.

Comment: @user6238251, I have updated my answer with a mechanism to be more selective about which folders can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks @john-bollinger

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` for this:

```
today="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
find /path/to/backuptest/Server* -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "$today" -exec rm -R {} \;
```

---

**Edit**

To not delete directories other than those containing a date structure, use something like

```
find /path/to/backuptest/Server* -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d  -regex ".*2016-[0-1]*[0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$" -not -name "$today"
```

Comment: This looks like the easy way. Mind that the op has another requirement now which is not met here..

Comment: @mona_sax : Updated

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with find:

```
set date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
find backuptest -type d -not -name $date -not -name "backuptest" -not -name "Server*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This:

```
find backuptest -type d -not -name $date -not -name "backuptest" -not -name "Server*"
```

will look for directories name different than:

```
backuptest
Server*
$date -> current date
```

and remove them with:

```
rm -rf
```